# MasterPageFile setting not working in Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage, 2016

I am working on custom branding using Visual Studio for SharePoint 2016 On-prem environment.

I got 2 masterpages (HomeResponsive16.master and Responsive16.master) and few page layouts. By default, Responsive16.master is set on the site. I want couple of page layouts (for instance Home-2Col.aspx) to use the other masterpage (i.e. HomeResponsive16.master) and not the default one.

My Home-2Col.aspx page layout's Page directive looks like this:

`<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="HomeResponsive16.master" CodeBehind="Home-2Col.aspx.cs" Inherits="ResponsiveToolkit._16.PageLayouts.Home_2Col, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>`

When I create a page (defaultnew.aspx) using the Home-2Col page layout, it still loads using the default master page rather than the one I set in the Page directive.

I also tried adding the code-behind for the page layout and setting the master page on the PreInit event but even that didn't work. I also confirmed that the SafeControl entry is present in the web.config for the code-behind.

Below is how my VS Solution looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this.

My Home-2Col.aspx page layout's Page directive looks now like this:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" CodeBehind="MyPageLayout.cs" Inherits="Toolkit.PageLayouts.MyPageLayout, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```

Added a codebehind file (MyPageLayouts.cs) under PageLayouts and added the below code to set the masterpage.

```
namespace Toolkit.PageLayouts
{
    public class MyPageLayout : Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage
    {
        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            this.MasterPageFile = "HomeResponsive16.master";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue at your `masterpagefile` path at Page directive, so make sure that the new master page has been deployed correctly to `http://rootsite/_catalogs/masterpage/` then try to change the path file at Page directive as the following

```
masterpagefile="../_catalogs/masterpage/HomeResponsive16.master"
```

**[Update]**

The above suggestion is for a Sharepoint Page, But when I read the quest again he talks about page layout.

**the Page Layout** in SharePoint allows you to create a template for a page that users apply to their content for a consistent layout of information.

So you can develop your page layout using VS and set it as a template to SharePoint page and at SharePoint page you can set its custom Master Page.

You can read more about page layout [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/04/02/page-layouts-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Dear @SagirKazi , take your time to test this solution and Please don't forget to set this as answer in case it's solved your issue and also upvote it if it's useful to you , I am also here if you need more clarification :)

Comment: I did verify that my custom masterpage is deployed correctly and that the right path (all variations) is mentioned in the Page directive in Page Layout but still no progress.

Comment: should you provide me with the path that master page has been deployed on it ?

Comment: Below is from the Elements.xml file for MasterPages.
  <Module Name="MasterPages" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="MasterPages" List="116" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
    <File Path="HomeResponsive16.master" Url="HomeResponsive16.master" ReplaceContent="TRUE" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="HomeResponsive16 MasterPage"></Property>
      <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="15" />
      <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="" />
    </File>
  </Module>

Comment: Because Comments are not for extended discussion kindly join this room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43413/discution-site-template-publishing-template

Comment: Getting this error or rather message when I click on the chat link: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq. This is so frustrating...

Comment: Ok , Dear as you mention you tried to create default.aspx and tried to change the master page via code but it also not works because it's also page layout so try to create SharePoint page not page layout and check if you can change its master page or not where I think you can't change master page for specific page layout because it inherits from master page setting of the whole site . check and update me please

Comment: sorry if I dint understood your comment. As mentioned in my OP, I did create a new sharepoint page (defaultnew.aspx). If I change the master page from site settings then the change is reflected on this new page as well.

Comment: is this page created below PageLayout module or it's a normal SharePoint page ?

Comment: the page is NOT created in Visual studio. I manually created the page from website by selecting my custom page layout.

Comment: No try to do this page via visual studio out side page layout module and set its master page , I am sure it should be changed ,

Comment: Creating the page in visual studio would not help as our business users create new pages daily using the custom page layouts. Also, the same code and structure is working for me in SharePoint Server 2010. So I know that I we can assign/change the masterpage from custom page layout.

Comment: I updated my answer and I hope it helps you and I respect your appreciation to my time :)

Comment: thanks for your update tom my answer but are you get solution ?